# Regex to filter out URL protocol but not domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some weird cases where I'm getting url's in the below format:

`http://http://www.somedomain.com/testing/ased=http://something`

I need them to come out like this: `www.somedomain.com/testing/ased=http://something`

They may or may not have www and they could be other things besides .com. They could also be `https` but the big issue is I need to filter out the protocol before the domain, but if the domain has a protocol in it, keep that.

I was using a replace with `/.*?:\/\//g` and replacing it with an empty string, but that doesn't work on the weird ones where there's a protocol in the domain.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some RegEx and non-capturing groups to do this. I would caution that you might want to look into where the data is coming from and try to clean it before it gets to you but I also understand that sometimes that isn't an option.

Here is some RegEx that will do what you need

`(?:http(s)?:\/\/)+(?<resource>.*[^\=]*.*)/gm`

This breaks down as follows:

`(?:http(s)?:\/\/)+`

This matches http:// and https:// one or more times and puts it into a non-capturing group.

`(?<resource>.*)`

This grabs everything after the first non-capturing group and puts it into a named-group "resource"

Here is a JavaScript code snippet that puts that into action:

```js
 // get your url
let string = "http://https://www.somedomain.com/testing/ased=http://something"
// build your regex
let regex = /(?:http(s)?:\/\/)+(?<resource>.*)/gm;
// get the matched groups
const { groups: { resource } } = regex.exec(string)
// log the resource group
console.log(resource)
```

Comment: Awesome, this got me exactly what I needed and showed me a super powerful new tool. Thanks so much.